# Roblox ScreenGUI problems

Tags: roblox

I was wondering if there was a thing that I had to do in order to change the text of a GUI mid-game. Because my problem is that I'm making a timer that goes through "Round in progress", "Game Over", "Intermission", "Voting in progress," and then repeat forever. But the text itself gets stuck on Round In Progress. Throughout the timer, the text value in the properties of the label changes, but the text doesn't change on the screen GUI

I've been changing the text with the same method every time:

```
status.Text = "Game over"
```

then I'd have the timer go about 5 seconds before I change it again:

```
status.Text = "Intermission"
```

And so on in a loop...

This is the whole code:

```
local rep = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local minutesvalue = rep:WaitForChild("Minutes")
local secondsvalue = rep:WaitForChild("Seconds")
local minutes = 0 --minutes
local seconds = 11 --seconds
local status = game.StarterGui.Status:WaitForChild("Status")

while true do
    status.Text = "Round In Progress"
    minutesvalue.Value = minutes
    secondsvalue.Value = seconds

    repeat
        if secondsvalue.Value <= 0 then
            minutesvalue.Value = minutesvalue.Value - 1
            secondsvalue.Value = 59
        else
            secondsvalue.Value = secondsvalue.Value - 1
        end
        wait(1)
    until secondsvalue.Value <= 0 and minutesvalue.Value <= 0

    status.Text = "Game Over!"

    wait(5)

    status.Text = "Intermission"
    secondsvalue.Value = 15

    repeat
        secondsvalue.Value = secondsvalue.Value - 1
        wait(1)
    until secondsvalue.Value <= 0 and minutesvalue.Value <= 0

    status.Text = "Voting In Progress"

    secondsvalue.Value = 10
    repeat
        secondsvalue.Value = secondsvalue.Value - 1
        wait(1)
    until secondsvalue.Value <= 0 and minutesvalue.Value <= 0
    status.Text = "Loading Map..."

end
```

The Timer and the Status are separate GUIs.
I separated it in the hope that it would work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing it in the StarterGui, I'm sure, do it in the players PlayerGui so replace:

`local status = game.StarterGui.Status:WaitForChild("Status")`

with:

`local status = players[plr].PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Status")`

(Define plr)

Comment: Or change the PlayerGui to PlayerGui.Status:WaitForChild("Status") if there is 2 status objects.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Is there a certain way I should do it to make it the same for everyone? This way, if I reset, the clock resets and the script plays again at the start.

Comment: You could make a for loop through players and set it that way, also can you mark the answer down as the actual answer please?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.